# How to run animation when ng-repeat finished binding?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dK5l0hzQXIPnRxFq1eyH) which demonstrate following behavior:
class *ng-hide* is removed from tag before ng-repeat finished create html view of data, so when removeClass is triggered height of element is not final and animation wouldn't correct.

Any solutions for sync data binding and animation?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <button ng-click="container.toggle()">Toggle</button>
      <ul class="animation-slider" ng-show="container.show">
        <li ng-repeat="item in container.items">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngAnimate'
])

.factory('Container', function($q, $timeout) {
  return function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    var container = {
      show: false,
      items: []
    };

    promise.then(function(data) {
      container.items = data;
      container.show = true;
    });

    container.toggle = function() {
      if (!container.show && container.items.length === 0) {
        container.load();
      } else {
        container.show = !container.show;
      }
    };

    container.load = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve([
          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque feugiat arcu in ligula euismod, vitae rhoncus erat porttitor. In vel metus pulvinar metus fermentum dapibus id nec ligula. Nam ac justo id dolor euismod ornare. Morbi sit amet odio quis sapien sodales ornare dignissim eu risus. Nunc efficitur bibendum odio. Quisque vehicula maximus purus vel blandit. Ut eu molestie urna. Nulla elit ligula, tincidunt sit amet iaculis lobortis, elementum et nunc. Nulla eu egestas massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis consequat cursus nibh ut sodales. Mauris sit amet neque volutpat, sodales lectus a, elementum sapien. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et blandit nulla. Duis eget tempus lorem.',
          'Mauris sit amet sodales massa. Pellentesque ut nunc tempus, maximus mauris consectetur, vehicula ex. Vivamus urna urna, lacinia in eros nec, pulvinar porta augue. Proin ullamcorper lacinia purus vitae efficitur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in massa in sem iaculis posuere sit amet nec elit. Ut ac nulla eget lorem tristique porta. Aenean ac consequat sem.',
          'Donec luctus leo a libero vehicula, consequat ullamcorper tortor facilisis. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam sed ultrices nibh, vel maximus enim. Aenean eu nulla vitae lorem commodo tempor. Donec sollicitudin tristique est. Phasellus lobortis et orci vitae posuere. Maecenas auctor cursus porttitor.'
        ]);
        //deferred.resolve([1,2]);
      }, 1000);
    };

    return container;
  };
})

.animation('.animation-slider', function() {
  return {
    beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done) {
      if (className === 'ng-hide') {
        TweenMax.to(element, 1, {
          height: 0,
          onComplete: done
        });

        return function() {
          element[0].style.height = '';
        };
      } else {
        done();
      }
    },
    removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
      if (className === 'ng-hide') {
        var height = element[0].clientHeight;
        console.log(height);
        element.css('height', 0);

        TweenMax.to(element, 1, {
          height: height,
          onComplete: done
        });

        return function() {
          element[0].style.height = '';
        };
      } else {
        done();
      }
    }
  };
})

.controller('MainController', function($scope, Container) {
  $scope.container = Container();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `container.show` to `true` only after the last `ng-repeat` element has been stamped out, you can create a directive that watches for the `$last` property to be `true` on the stamped out elements. When it's `true`, that directive could then set `container.show` to `true`.

So your HTML would look like this, with a new `handle-last-item-stamped` directive on your repeating `li` element:

```
<ul class="animation-slider" ng-show="container.show">
  <li ng-repeat="item in container.items" handle-last-item-stamped="$last">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the new directive would look like this (I injected `$timeout` in case you need to add a slight delay before showing):

```
.directive('handleLastItemStamped', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$watch(attrs.handleLastItemStamped, function (newVal, oldVal){
        if (newVal) {
          scope.container.show = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }  
}]);
```

And, of course, you'd have to remove the `container.show = true;` from your `promise.then`.

Here's a plunk with these changes:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nVG6gh7vabYhqg5nAula

Comment: Its genius idea! Thx for the detailed answer!